# in a table column row by row subtraction to find the value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
id  patient_date            
1   10/5/2017           
2   6/6/2017            
3   6/10/2017           
4   8/7/2017            
5   9/19/2017
```

Output:

```
id   patient_date      days     
1   10/5/2017        (6/6/2017-10/5/2017)       
2   6/6/2017         (6/10/2017-6/6/2017)       
3   6/10/2017        (8/7/2017-6/10/2017)       
4   8/7/2017         (9/19/2017-8/7/2017)       
5   9/19/2017
```

Comment: Read this [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Comment: Is your data ordered by ID or by patient_date? Somehow the order of the examples provided by you doesn't make mich sense...ID 1 has the newest date, ID 5 the second newest...

Answer (score 1):

Here's query with extra column for you to choose :)

```
declare @Table table(ID int identity(1,1), patient_date date)

insert into @Table values
 ('10/5/2017'),
 ('6/6/2017'),
 ('6/10/2017'),
 ('8/7/2017'),
 ('9/19/2017')

 select A.ID,
        A.patient_date,
        cast(B.patient_date as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + cast(A.patient_date as varchar(10)) as Period, --this column will show exactly what you asked
        abs(datediff(day,B.patient_date, A.patient_date)) as DaysDifference --this column is computed absolute difference in days between to dates
 from @Table A left join @Table B on A.ID = B.ID - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This will use lead to find your next value. The last value should either be null or nothing, correct it as you need.
The date 1900-01-01 should be changed to your desired wishes. It could also be NULL as value. Then it wont calculate the last row.

```
 DECLARE @table TABLE (ID int,Patient_date date)
 INSERT INTO @table VALUES

 (1, '10/5/2017'),
 (2,'6/6/2017'),
 (3,'6/10/2017'),
 (4,'8/7/2017'),
 (5,'9/19/2017')

 select *,DATEDIFF(DD,Patient_date,NextDate) as DaysBetween, 
'('+cast(Patient_date as varchar(50)) + ' - ' + cast(NextDate  as 
varchar(50))+')' as DayString from (
select *,LEAD(Patient_date,1,'1900-01-01')  over(order by ID ) as NextDate 
from @table
) x
```

In my result i used NULL instead of 1900-01-01 - Also notice i use another date format than you, but it shouldnt be a problem.

**Result:**

[image]